# How to avoid losing remote information when using git?

Tags: git, git-clone, git-mirror

My objective is to simplify the process of updating my git mirror clones.

I have a git repository `repo-A` which is given by a supplier
I have a git repository `repo-B` which is in my local git

I am able to clone repo-A add repo-B as a remote and push to repo-B. With this commands

```
git clone --mirror repo-A
git remote add  my-local-server repo-B
git push --mirror my-local-server
```

The result is that `repo-B` contains the same branches, commits, etc than `repo-A`. At this point I can fetch new code from `repo-A` and push it to `repo-B`

The problem is that if I clone `repo-B` in another computer. The configuration of the remotes is lost.

This means that if I do a git remote -v only the links to `repo-B` are present.

**Is it possible to configure `repo-B` so that even after a fresh clone remote repositories links are present?**

My objective is to be able to do

```
git clone repo-B
git fetch --all origin /* or the name of location repo-A is located */
git push --all my-local-server
```

I know that a similar behaviour can be achieved by

```
git clone --mirror repo-A
git push --mirror repo-B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to configure repo-B so that even after a fresh clone remote repositories links [to repo-A] are present?

No.

Remember, `git clone` means:

1. make a new, empty directory;
2. run `git init` in the new empty directory;
3. run `git remote add` in the new clone;
4. run `git config` in the new clone if/as directed by options you supplied to `git clone`;
5. run `git fetch` in the new clone; and
6. run `git checkout` in the new clone.

Only step 4 could do what you want—the `git remote add` in step 3 is so that step 5 will fetch from repo-B—and step 4 only obeys arguments you supply on the command line.

You have two options:

1. Don't use `git clone`, at least not directly.  Write your own program that runs `git clone`, inspects the new clone, then runs `git remote add` as desired.  Or,
2. Use `git clone` via an alias or script that adds appropriate `-c` options so that step 4 sets up a remote.  `git remote add` consists of running several `git config` operations: specifically, you must set `remote.name.url` and `remote.name.fetch`.  So you can do these with the `git clone` command line.

Note that both of these are quite similar: the real difference is whether you get repo A's URL from something retrieved from repo B, or hard-code it.  If you choose to get the URL from something retrieved from repo B, remember that `git clone` copies all (reachable) *commits*, but no *branches:* step 6 is the one that creates a branch in the new clone.  You would need to encode repo A's URL in some data fetched in step 5: probably some commit, perhaps found by a specially coded remote-tracking name (i.e., a branch name in repo-B that becomes a remote-tracking name in your clone), or in some data to be found via some tag name.